# Adding dymatic data into phonegap plugin

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to dynamically add data into a phonegap plugin

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(
   null, 
   null, 
   'document.getElementById('setquote').innerHTML;', 
   null
)">
```

I have try using this `document.getElementById('setquote').innerHTML;` to get the data into the plugin but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the quotes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(
   null, 
   null, 
   document.getElementById('setquote').innerHTML,  <- remove quotes here
   null
)">
```

When you wrap that line in quotes, you're just passing a string, I think you want to pass the actual inner html

Comment: @kingv ok, in that case, my guess is that your innerHTML contains `"` characters. This could be escaping your string. Can you update your question with the innerHTML?

Comment: got it working, forgot to take out the `;` at the end of the innerHTML. Thanks for the help @jasonscript

Comment: this script is very useful but the problem i'm seeing is in sharing the message it includes the html attribute eg. <br> <p> etc.